# Using SumLookUp with LookUpSet produces #Error when visibility set to expand

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting

I am using `SumLookup( LookupSet` formula to sum groups.  The Groups have visibility set to hidden but can be toggled to visible.

When I click the plus sign to expand, the `SumLookup` shows as `#Error`.

Before attempting to expand the `SumLookup`, it shows the correct value.

This is my expression:

```
=code.SumLookup(lookupset(Fields!TTPrincipalSitesid.Value, Fields!Principalsid.Value,Fields!ClassContactHours.Value, "StaffHours"))
```

Which seems fine to me, but also when I preview the report, I get the following warning for each instance.

> [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox20.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Request
>   failed.

There are 3 different groups with this expression in, and regardless of what I try to expand, all 3 display as `#Error` when I try.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Provide a minimal reproducible example for example.

Comment: It looks like you're using a piece of custom code indicated by `Code.SumLookup`.  Could you provide the code that defines that function?

Comment: @Steve-o169

This is the code I used...and have used previously but not with hide/show option before, so not encountered this problem

`Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
If items Is Nothing Then
Return Nothing
End If
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
ct = 0
For Each item As Object In items
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
ct += 1
Next
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function`